# Is there any point to placing a lock within a non-static operation, particularly in a web service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

So I'm going through some of our code trying to clean some stuff up and I came across this bit, and I can't for the life of me figure out what purpose it serves:

```
public class SomeOperationBaseClass
{
    private readonly ISomeRepository _someRepository;

    // stuff...

    public SomeReturnType RunTransaction(SomeRequestType request)
    {
        SomeReturnType result;

        // some stuff happens here

        lock(request.UserId) 
        {
            // run some stuff

            var info = _someRepository.GetDatabaseLock(lockRequest); 

            lock(request.UserId) // lolwat?
            {
                // run some more stuff

                _someRepository.ReleaseDatabaseLock(releaseLockRequest);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Allegedly, all of this nonsense is to prevent a particular user's account from processing more than one thing at a time. The database "lock" just sets a flag stating that the user has something in progress; elsewhere in the code, it prevents this operation from running until it can get back a result saying that the user is not in the middle of something. It's some dirty workaround for not having any sort of cache server.

My main question is regarding the locks:

- The inner lock seems pointless. It's attempting to place a lock on
  the user id. I removed it.
- The database lock has to stay for now, so I left it alone
- The outer lock seems pointless. This is a WebAPI web
  service and this class is a base class of a child operation that is
  spun up as a result of an HttpRequest. As far as I understand, the
  request has it's own thread and that thread owns this instance of the
  class. It is not a static class nor a static method. No input
  parameters are being modified by reference. I don't see any issues of
  thread safety here.

With all that said, I'm pretty sure that both locks are pointless and I'd like to remove them. But if there is something else about the lock keyword that I am missing, I'd like some insight.

Comment: In the actual code, the requests are actually instantiated IN the arguments lists (e.g. ReleaseLock(new ReleaseLockRequest(...));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner lock is pointless.  You already have the lock on the request.UserId from the outer lock.

Without knowing more, the outer lock may be there to attempt to restrict access to the `GetDatabaseLock` method, or potentially an static variables/properties within the class.  So, if `SomeOperationBaseClass` contained a static variable, which was acted upon within `RunTransaction`, then you would want exclusive use of it.  However, in that case, I would expect the lock to be on a `private static`, or `private` variable.

Comment: Yeah there are no static anythings in this class

Comment: I know that you're just trying to figure it out, but from the info you provided I would say that someone didn't understand what they were doing and were placing the locks there to be overly cautious.

Now locking the database on the other hand...probably not a good idea ;-)

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly. That's actually the reason I'm in there cleaning it up. That dude left a mess everywhere before he was finally let go. This is a critical component though, so I'm treading lightly as I burn his trash out of there. :)